# C# date picker 24 h date and time

Tags: c#

Hello i am actually using datepicker in my c # application. In order to pick up both date and time i have used the following setting in the property:

```
format = custom
customformat = dd MM yyyy hh mm ss
```

this works fine but only displays hours minutes ranging 1 to 12, i want to be able to represent hours from 0 to 23. any advice? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try please HH instead of hh:

format = custom

customformat = dd MM yyyy HH mm ss

Further reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
customformat = dd MM yyyy HH mm ss
```

i.e use upper case H instead of lower case h.

Answer (score 0):

you can set custom format `dd MM yyyy HH mm ss` as per your requirement. you can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for custom format. Similarly you can read its value in `DateTime` using [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) as :

```
 string strDateStarted = datetimepicker1.Value.Tostring();
 DateTime datDateStarted;
 DateTime.TryParseExact(strDateStarted, new string[] { "dd MM yyyy HH mm ss" }, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDateStarted);
 Console.WriteLine(datDateStarted);
```